# Serve aggregate CSS/JS files from S3 instead of local storage

Tags: css-js-aggregation, 8

I have enabled aggregate CSS/JS from the backend. It stores the aggregated files in the local system. How do I make them accessible through the S3 bucket? I have already installed the [S3fs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs).

The point is when my server is down it automatically creates another instance. And that newly created instance does not have the previous aggregated CSS/JS files. Therefore, it breaks my website.

Answer (score 1):

It's all explained in the module's [README.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/s3fs/blob/8.x-3.x/README.txt)

> - This will configure your site to store new uploaded files in S3.
>     Files
>     which your site creates automatically (such as aggregated CSS) will still
>     be stored in the server's local filesystem, because Drupal is hard-coded
>     to use the `public:// filesystem` for such files.
> - However, s3fs can be configured to handle these files as well. In
>     **settings.php** you can enable the `s3fs.use_s3_for_public` and
>     `s3fs.use_s3_for_private` settings to make s3fs take over the job of the
>     public and/or private file systems. This will cause your site to store
>     newly uploaded/generated files from the public/private file system in S3
>     instead of the local file system. However, it will make any existing files
>     in those file systems become invisible to Drupal.
>     To remedy this, you'll need to copy those files into your S3 bucket.
>
>   Example:
>     `$settings['s3fs.use_s3_for_public'] = TRUE;`
> - If you use s3fs for public, you should change your php twig
>     storage folder
>     to a local directory, php twig files in S3 produce latency and security
>     issues (these files would be public). Please change the `php_storage settings` in your **setting.php** and choose a directory, out of docroot
>     recommended.
>
>   Example:
>     `$settings['php_storage']['twig']['directory'] = '../storage/php';`
>
>   If you have a multiple backends you may use a NAS to store it or other
>     shared storage system with your others backends.

---

Related Question: [Serve compressed JS and CSS with S3 as filesystem](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/274873/serve-compressed-js-and-css-with-s3-as-filesystem)